# How to detect a change of "state" and display something?

Tags: templates, plone

With Plone 3.3.5, I have a classical foldercontents which is a list of events sorted by date (reverse). I am displaying each element one by one. I would like to display a special message when events are no longer in the future but are past events.

For now, I have this:

```
  <span tal:define="endDate item/end; 
           " tal:condition="python: endDate.isPast()">Past event<br />
  </span>
```

But I would like to display only once this message and not for all past events...

I tried creating a Python variable but failed to do so (mess with the undeclared variable).

Thanks for the help

PS: I am not familiar at all with the template language of Plone...

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would probably be to just make them two lists that you iterate over: one for future events and one for past events.  Then you can just put 'Past events' as header between the to lists.

Comment: I like this idea but the problem with this solution is that I would have to duplicate some code here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can count the events in the future and display the appropriate message if this becomes 0.

See the "events" collection at the root of the portal for an example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
it may be appears a little bit tricky, cause this approach comes natural when managing db results set.

You can refer here:
http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#the-following-information-is-available-from-the-repeat-variable

The tal:repeat statement is very powerful and, in your case you can count on "first" variable information.

Instead of a simple List of Events, try to iterate over a list of dictionaries in which you take care of isPast information.

Run the following (simple and brutal) tal code... it is self explaning.

```
<div tal:define="past string:Past events;
                 future string:Events to Come;
                 richList python:[{'event':'event1', 'passed': past},
                                  {'event':'event2', 'passed': future},
                                  {'event':'event3', 'passed': past},
                                  {'event':'event4', 'passed': future}];
                 dummy python:richList.sort(lambda x,y:cmp(x['passed'], y['passed']))">    


    <tal:block repeat="item richList">
        <h2 tal:condition="repeat/item/first/passed"
            tal:content="item/passed">
            Past Events or Future
        </h2>
      <a tal:content="item/event">event's url</a>
        </tal:block>

    </div>
```

You can create your richList iterating on the result of a catalog call. And you can create the dictionary item seting 'passed' value according with event/end/isPast function.

hope this helps.

Comment: I wasn't aware of such capabilities. Thanks for pointing this out. 
My only problem is now to understand how to connect your idea with my current application. The following is doing:  
<span tal:condition="repeat/item/first  /end/isPast()" tal:content="item/end">Past Events or Future<br /> </span>  
as   
<span tal:define="endDate   item/end; " tal:condition="python: endDate.isPast()">Past event<br /></span>

Comment: you cannot do path/path/func(). You have to write a path expression XOR a python expression. You must take a look at "tal overview" documentation before proceeding ;)

BTW, it's better to delegate to a python script (or a browser view class) the task of fetching your events. After that you can create a dict like mine in order to use the "first" magic word.

Answer (score 1):

You can "filter" in listFolderContents exactly as you can filter when doing a catalog search.
See http://collective-docs.plone.org/content/listing.html#getting-folder-objects-filtered
for how this is done. There is already an "end" index which you can include in your filter, see http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/searching-and-indexing/query#querying-by-date